# KINETIC.JS loading image from stored json

Tags: jquery, json, html, load, kineticjs

I was able to load multiple image at once from a dummy json string that I created with json = stage.toJSON();. Offline this works flawlessly and it even remembers the position that I dragged it too. However when I put it onto my server only the first image appears and the rest are hidden until I click on the position where it is positioned. Is this a matter of server performance? The code that upload to my server are identical. For testing purpose I am only using godaddy for hosting. Thank you

Any help is valuable to me.

Comment: try redrawing the layers, that worked for me when my images wouldn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Can not be a server issue since you are working on the client side. Probably its working on your machine because have already cached the images.

Check that you are caching all images present in stage definition (check src of image objects) previous to add them to kinetics layer (for example placing a hidden div with all images and using window.load event), otherwise you will be calling draw event before images are fully loaded.

Hope this helps